# Insertion at specific place in file java

Tags: java, inputstream, file-handling, outputstream

I have a code have two byte arrays named array and buffer. First array insert data at the start of output file and second array then start from where first array end. I want to insert first array (array) at specific location of second array. How can I do

```
    byte[] array = null;
    outputStream.write(array);

    // Now
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(book.update(buffer, 0, len));
        outputStream.flush();
    }
    outputStream.write(book.doFinal());
```

Comment: It isn't clear from your description whether you want to insert data into an array or a file.

Comment: Also, you say first you want to insert first array at the start of an output file, and then you say you want to insert the first array into a specific location in the second array.  Seems contradictory without further explanation.

Comment: First array writes data at start and second array writes after first array. I dont want to write first array at start, I want to writes somewhere in between second array in file.

Comment: What's preventing you from writing part of the second array, then switching to the first array, and then going back to write the rest of the second array?

Comment: You can use `outputStream.write(array, offset, length)`, which allows you to write however much of the second array you want, then write the first array, and then use the `offset` argument to write the rest of the second array.

Comment: Simply I want to hide first array in between second array at specific location, means write second array half then write first array and then write remaining second half.

Comment: I just told you how to do that.

Comment: Can you kindly share the rough code which may help me.

Comment: That is the "rough code" I gave you.

Comment: What about it do you not understand?

Comment: I understood what you said but I dont know how to use it.

Comment: Look up OutputStream's write function with 3 arguments.  The first argument is the array to be written.  The second is the offset (where in the array to start), and the 3rd is the length of data to be written.

Comment: Also, remember that `array.length` tells you the array's length.

Comment: Can you share few lines of code ? which may help me more than theoretical answers. I understood you point and parameters list. But how to use them, kindly share few lines of code

Comment: What I've given should be enough for you to figure out the answer.

Comment: You can always wait for someone else to spoon feed you the answer, but I am not willing to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much friend.